Anime film about Smurf like blue guys with white hoods raiding a convoy
I saw this anime movie after midnight on television, when I was 10 years old and visiting my family in Moskow, Russia in the year 2009-2010. I perhaps would be able to tell a certain time that it was made in, based on the quality, but I'm not sure. I assume it was made well before the time I saw it.
This movie was stylistically violent and disturbing to me and my brother. There was an army of short, blue guys with white hoods; they kind of looked like smurfs. The opening scene of this movie I think involved the army of smurfs raiding a convoy. The central plot had to do with two men and a lady. 
This movie is graphic and about crime. What's the name of this movie?

Could you tell us what year it was when you were 10? That might be more helpful :)

I edited the post.

Do you have any more information about the actual plot of the movie or any more descriptions of scenes? You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

I didn't really appreciate that you cut out that sentimental piece that I mentioned, how people relate to seeing one movie that they wonder about later on. I guess you did make a decent edit overall though.

My man Alex found the movie. Thanks a lot, chum.

Maybe Aachi & Ssipak

In a future where energy is made from fecal matter, the government rewards defecation with "juicybars". Small-time hustlers try to get rich while fending off the mutated Diaper Gang.





This is the movie, thanks.
